# Changing the default title/author/institution/frametitle font in Beamer

Tags: beamer, fonts, titles

I sadly haven't been able to answer this questions using Google. In `beamer`, I'd like to make the default font for the entire title page, as well as frame titles, to be the default font from the old [`prosper` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/prosper) (example [here](http://amath.colorado.edu/documentation/LaTeX/prosper/0/prosper_intro.pdf)).

[image]

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if this is exhaustive but I'm fairly confident that these are the only fonts available in Beamer. [Beamer Fonts](http://deic.uab.es/~iblanes/beamer_gallery/index_by_font.html)

Comment: Sorry, have you already got the font to work everywhere but the title frame? Or do you want that font to apply to the title frame ONLY?

Comment: I haven't been able to get the font anywhere -- I've seen Beamer presentations which use the font as the default for the title page and frame titles (example: http://latex.simon04.net/img/carlworld.png). However, this example uses .sty files and I'm just looking for something a little simpler

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Found a solution:

```
    \usefonttheme{structurebold}
    \setbeamerfont{title}{series=\bfseries,parent=structure}
    \setbeamerfont{subtitle}{size=\scriptsize,series=\bfseries,parent=structure}
    \setbeamerfont{author}{size=\scriptsize,series=\bfseries,parent=structure}
    \setbeamerfont{institute}{size=\scriptsize,series=\bfseries,parent=structure}
    \setbeamerfont{date}{size=\scriptsize,series=\bfseries,parent=structure}
```

Comment: Can you explain what `parent=structure` means?